# Set event listeners on iFrame before load

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Lets say I am on `example.com`, and I have an iFrame of `example.com`. (yes they are the same) I need to catch errors that happen within the iFrame. How can I set an event listener in the iFrame, before it's script elements start loading?

I have seen it done before, on [repl.it](https://repl.it) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this ->

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="https://google.ca"></iframe>



<script>
 myframe.onload = function(){
 var that = document.getElementById('myframe');

 try{
    (that.contentWindow||that.contentDocument).location.href;
 }
 catch(err){
    //err:SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://*********" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    console.log('err:'+err);
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: That checks for cross-origin errors, but my iFrame is the same domain so I won't have that problem.